# ROS communication works only in one direction

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS Kinetic and I have a strange issue.

I want to run one node in a Docker container on my pc and one node on a RaspberryPi.
The problem is that if I publish messages from the pc, no message is received on the Raspberry.
Interestingly if I publish from the Raspberry I receive messages on the pc.

I tried to run the ROS master both on the pc as well as on the Raspberry.
In the `.bashrc` file of both devices I have the following lines

```
  export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://masterhost:11311
  export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
```

Where `localhost` is the ip address of the specific device and  `masterhost` is equal to the localhost of the device running the master.

Do you know why this could happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305613/ros-communication-works-only-in-one-direction/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `pc` and the `raspberry` shouldn't have the same configuration. They have to have the **same** `ROS_MASTER_URI` but their `ROS_HOSTNAME` (or `ROS_IP`) should be their own.

You should have in the `.bashrc`:

- On the pc :

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://PC_IP_ADDRESS:11311`

`export ROS_HOSTNAME=PC_IP_ADDRESS`

- On the rapsberry :

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://PC_IP_ADDRESS:11311`

`export ROS_HOSTNAME=RASPBERRY_IP_ADDRESS`

See [#q272065](https://answers.ros.org/question/272065/specification-of-ros_master_uri-and-ros_hostname/) for a much more detailled answer.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-12**:
Note that a complicating factor here could be the Docker setup. Docker by default uses NAT (ie: masquerading), so it's not always as straightforward as setting `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` to get things to work.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-12**:
Does the masqueradidng change the `ROS_MASTER_URI` ? If not, is it possible to replace`PC_IP_ADDRESS` for the `ROS_MASTER_URI` by `RASPBERRY_IP_ADDRESS` to prevent the issue ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-12**:
Docker creates a "virtual network" by default, so depending on where you run your master you'll have to update the `ROS_MASTER_URI` yes (and most likely the routing configuration of the involved hosts). But the more difficult issue is that NAT will "hide" nodes running inside your container.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-12**:
@Delb the `ROS_HOSTNAME` is different across devices, It was not clear from my question.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-12**:
@gvdhoorn You are right, the error is due to the Docker setup.
I'm running the container with the `--privileged` and `--net=host` flags.
From `ifconfig` inside Docker, I see the `docker` and `wlan` interfaces. I am using the `wlan` inet address in the exported env variables